# xpath to locate a button whose id is dynamic in Robot FrameWork

Tags: xpath, robotframework

I am using RobotFramework for automation testing, I am facing an issue in clicking a button whose id is dynamic in nature, its a '+' symbol on clicking i will get a popup window.

```html
<div id="button-1571" class="x-btn x-box-item x-toolbar-item x-btn-default-toolbar-small x-icon x-btn-icon x-btn-default-toolbar-small-icon" style="border-width: 1px; left: 373px; margin: 0px; top: 6px;">

    <em id="button-1571-btnWrap">
        <button id="button-1571-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" style="height: 16px;">
            <span id="button-1571-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="margin: -1px 0px;"></span>
            <span id="button-1571-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon icon-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </em>

</div>
```

Below is the code i used to click the button

Click Button    `xpath=//div[@id='button-1571']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]`

But its not Working can any one please suggest how to solve this issue

Comment: i tried by giving only id also it didn't work, Got error like no match found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only test the XPath, but with

```
//div[@id='button-1571']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/  
                         span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]
```

it's not the `button` that is selected, but the `span`:

```
<span id="button-1571-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon icon-plus" />
```

When changing the XPath to

```
//div[@id='button-1571']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/  
                         span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]/..
```

or, just as second notation

```
//div[@id='button-1571']/descendant::button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/
                     span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]/parent::button
```

it's the parent `button` of this `span`, result of above XPath:

```
<button id="button-1571-btnEl" class="x-btn-center" autocomplete="off" 
        role="button" hidefocus="true" type="button" style="height: 16px;">
  <span id="button-1571-btnInnerEl" class="x-btn-inner" style="margin: -1px 0px;" />
  <span id="button-1571-btnIconEl" class="x-btn-icon icon-plus" />
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks matthias_h, it was helpful //button[contains(@class, 'x-btn-center')]/span[contains(@class,'x-btn-icon icon-plus')]/parent::button using above code i was able to click that button.